# How to get a difference between two input variables in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a program, in Python. I have came over a slight patch. What I'm trying to do is simple. Calculate the difference between two numbers that the user has input into the program.

```
nameA = input("Enter your first German warriors name: ")

print( nameA,"the noble.")

print("What shall",nameA,"the noble strength be?") 

strengthA = input("Choose a number between 0-100:")

print("What shall",nameA,"the noble skill be?") 

skillA = input("Choose a number between 0-100:")

#Playerb

nameB = input("Enter your first German warriors name: ")

print( nameB,"the brave.")

print("What shall",nameB,"the noble strength be?") 

strengthB = input("Choose a number between 0-100:")

print("What shall",nameB,"the brave skill be?") 

skillB = input("Choose a number between 0-100:")
```

I' trying to calculate the difference between what the user has input for StrengthA and StrengthB.

This question maybe a little noobish. But, we all have to learn. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `-` operator, then find the `abs()` of that to get the difference between two numbers.

```
abs(StrengthA - StrengthB)
```

However you must first make sure you are working with integers. Do this by:

```
StrengthA = int(input())  # Do the same with StrengthB.
```

---

**EDIT:**

To find that overall divided by five, you would just do:

```
(abs(StrengthA - StrengthB)) / 5
```

Comment: this has worked so far. how then would this over all difference be dived by 5? can you help?

Comment: Thanks! Alex. Sorry. I'm a little new to this. :)

Comment: @user3529441 That's quite alright, and I'm happy to help. If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting it? You can do that by clicking the tick below the vote counts so that it turns green. Thank you.

Comment: Did it. But can I ask one more favour- How could I round the total of this number. Then create a 'strength modifier'?

Comment: @user3529441 Sure. Just pass it into the built-in `round()` function. As for a strength modifier, that is really a separate issue. You could always ask a different question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Code structure is really great for making your program easier to understand and maintain:

```
def get_int(prompt, lo=None, hi=None):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt))
            if (lo is None or lo <= value) and (hi is None or value <= hi):
                return value
        except ValueError:
            pass

def get_name(prompt):
    while True:
        name = input(prompt).strip()
        if name:
            return name.title()

class Warrior:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name     = get_name("Enter warrior's name: ")
        self.strength = get_int("Enter {}'s strength [0-100]: ".format(self.name), 0, 100)
        self.skill    = get_int("Enter {}'s skill [0-100]: "   .format(self.name), 0, 100)

def main():
    wa = Warrior()
    wb = Warrior()

    str_mod = abs(wa.strength - wb.strength) // 5

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```